# Table prompts are not working in OBI Answers 11g when i use union of two queries

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, obiee

Okay, so the two queries are from same subject area and they show results when there is no table prompt. But as soon i drag a column to the table prompt in view, it shows the data which should have resulted if I applied join. Please help

Comment: Please include the LSQL generated for each scenario, look at the advanced tab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query Wrapping is what i have used to solve this issue, the prompts are working normally now.